# How to callback Javascript into div and how to create + l +

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

how to make +k+ +l+ etc.

example:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function slide1(h) {
    img = [];
    maxpost = numposts <= h.feed.entry.length ? numposts : h.feed.entry.length;
    for (var g = 0; g < maxpost; g++) {
        var e = h.feed.entry[g],
            k = e.title.$t,
            l;
        if (g == h.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var f = 0; f < e.link.length; f++)
            if ("alternate" == e.link[f].rel) {
                l = e.link[f].href;
                break
            }
        s = "content" in e ? e.content.$t : "summary" in e ? e.summary.$t : "";
        a = s.indexOf("<img");
        b = s.indexOf('src="', a);
        c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5);
        d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5); - 1 != a && -l != b && -1 != c && "" != d && (img[g] = d);
        tennhan = [];
        if (cate = e.category)
            for (f = 0; f < e.category.length; f++) tennhan[f] = "" + e.category[f].term + "";
        else tennhan = "No label";
        0 <= g && 10 >= g && (e = '<div class="col2 col-md-9"><h2 itemprop="name">' + titvn(k) + '</h2><div class='name2'><dfn>' + altit(k) + '</dfn></div><dl><dt>Đăng bởi:</dt><dd class='status'><data:post.author/> - <data:post.timestamp/></dd><br/><dd><data:post.snippet/></dd></dl><div class='extra-info'><div class='views'> <i class='micon views'/> <span>1 Tỷ</span> </div><div class='like'> <i class='micon heart'/> <span>1 lượt</span> </div><div class='imdbs'> <i class='micon imdb'/> <span>N/A</span> </div></div></div></div>'
    }
    document.write("")
};
//]]></script>
```

How about if i just want to take this code

```html
'+ titvn(k) +'
```

into post page (HTML):

```html
<div class='test'><dfn>'+ titvn(k) +'></dfn></div>
```

I know this is wrong, please justify it.

Comment: You mean `document.getElementsByTagName("dfn")[0].innerHTML=object(k);`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that.. some event need to call the function. Only way to make it run automatically is on page onload event. When the page load you can code to call the function.. But not like this.

Comment: I hope you see again my new question that I changed, what is "function" like that?

Answer (score 0):

To run javascript within html (and I assume in a web browser) you need a `script` tag

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set the inner text of the selected node to something
    document.getElementById("test").innerText = ...
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply dude, but look again at the question I just changed dude :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="object = { k: 'some data', foo: 'bar' }"></div>

  <div class="test"><dfn>{{ object.k }}</dfn></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thankss! but please See again the question, i just changed :)